# win32com Powerpoint Cannot Handle Spaces In Name

Tags: python, win32com

A project of mine requires opening a variety of Microsoft Office documents as read-only through python. While the Excel and Word features of win32com have never had issues with documents containing spaces, win32com PowerPoint is not allowing it.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Application = Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
Application.Visible = True
Test = Application.Presentations.Open("C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/The Test.pptx", ReadOnly=True)
```

Produces error:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024894), None)
```

My current solution for this is to rename the file, replacing spaces with underscores, then to rename it back after the file is opened. However, this requires the document to be opened untitled.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os
Application = Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
Application.Visible = True
Filename = 'The Test.pptx'
os.rename("C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/" + Filename, "C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/" + Filename.replace(" ","_"))
Test = Application.Presentations.Open("C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/" + Filename.replace(" ","_"), ReadOnly=True, Untitled=True)
os.rename("C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/" + Filename.replace(" ","_"), "C:/Users/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/" + Filename)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Forward slashes and spaces worked fine in Python 2.7.12

Answer (score 1):

Using back-slashes should work:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def openfile():
    Application = Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
    Application.Visible = True
    Test = Application.Presentations.Open(r"C:\transfer\hello world.pptx", ReadOnly=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    openfile()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the problems occur if you are not preceding your strings with an "r". The "r" will tell python to treat the given string as a raw string.

It works for me if I try this:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Application = Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
Application.Visible = True
Test = Application.Presentations.Open(r"C:\UsersMYUSERNAME\Desktop\The Test.pptx", ReadOnly=True)
```